# Using std::enable::if and std::is_base_of to constraint inherintance

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, inheritance

Given the following scenario:

```
class A {};
class B : public A {};
class C : public A {};
class D : public A {};

template<typename T/*std::enable_if and std::is_base_of here*/> class X {};
```

When I declare an X

Then I want to constraint the `typename T` to obligatorily be a sub-class of A, otherwise I'll get a compiling error.

```
int main()
{
   X<B> x1 = {}; //should work;
   X<C> x2 = {}; //should work;
   X<D> x2 = {}; //should work;
   X<std::string> = {};  //should generate a compiling error;
   X<int> = {};  //should generate a compiling error;
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A correct syntax for using `enable_if` is

```
template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<A, T>, bool> = true> 
class X {};
```

and now if `A` is a base of `T` then `std::is_base_of_v<A, T>` is `true` and `std::enable_if_t` becomes `bool` and we give it the value of `true`.  If `A` is not a base of `T` then the condition is false and `std::enable_if_t` results to nothing and the template is discarded as a viable candidate and a compiler error will be generated.

Comment: You can also do `std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<A, T>, std::nullptr_t> = nullptr`, then you don't have to worry about user messing with the second template parameter.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat How is that any different?  You're using `std::nullptr_t` and `nullptr` instead of `bool` and `true`, which is more typing.

Comment: With `nullptr_t` there's only one possible template argument, so the user can't create more than one specialization. I admit that it's somewhat paranoid though.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, `static_assert` might be enough:

```
template<typename T>
class X {
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<A, T>::value, "!");
};
```

Comment: I would put a diagnostic string in the `static_assert`. compilers are crazy.

Comment: @Red.Wave: I don't see meaningful message with doesn't paraphrase the condition. especially in toy example.

Comment: @interjay: I didn't notice C++11 flag :/

Comment: Come on. Don't be stingy; throw some more words. One major reason for inclusion of `static_assert` was that compiler generated diagnostics were messy. Otherwise `static_assert` can be implemented as a crazy macro.

Answer (score 3):

A third and likewise common variation to

- `static_assert` from [Jarod42:s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64808284/4573247), and
- using `std::enable_if_t` as the type of a non-type template parameter defaulted to some value (`template<..., std::enable_if_t<..., bool> = true>`) from [NathanOliver's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64808251/4573247)

is to use `std::enable_if_t` as the default template argument to a *type template parameter* (as compared as the type of a non-type template parameter):

```
template<typename T, 
         typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<A, T>>> 
class X {};
```

this is somewhat briefer than using the non-type template parameter approach.

It comes with the drawback, however, that when used for function templates it cannot be combined with, say SFINAE-overloading two variations solely based on opposite results for a predicate:

```
// Not OK.
template<typename T, 
         typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<A, T>>> 
void foo(const T&) { /* some impl */ }

// Error: re-definition of foo
template<typename T, 
         typename = std::enable_if_t<!std::is_base_of_v<A, T>>>
void foo(const T&) { /* another impl */ }
```

as both overloads differ only in their default template arguments, which is not part of the function template's signature, they declare two different function templates with the same signature, which is illegal.

If we non-type template approach instead, this is not an issue:

```
// OK
template<typename T, 
         std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<A, T>>* = nullptr> 
void foo(const T&) { /* some impl */ }


template<typename T, 
         std::enable_if_t<!std::is_base_of_v<A, T>>* = nullptr> 
void foo(const T&) { /* another impl */ }
```